# how to parse process.stdin/process.stdout of child_process.spawn stdio

Tags: node.js

I try wrap command in node script and parse stdin/out stream for add/replace string.

It's for auto insert ssh/sudo password for example, I don't want use `expect` because it's too rigid. Like trigger fonctionnality of iTerm2 but terminal agnostic.

If you know tool for this or if you have a better idea, you are welcome =D!

I try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const child_process = require('child_process');
const command = ['vi', ['index.js']];

let spawned_process = child_process.spawn(...command, {
    env: process.env,
    shell: '/bin/bash',
    stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr]
});
```

This work very well but I don't find how access to `process.stdin` and `process.stdout`.

I try this too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const child_process = require('child_process');
const command = ['vi', ['index.js']];

let spawned_process = child_process.spawn(...command, {
    env: process.env,
    shell: '/bin/bash',
    stdio: [process.stdin, 'pipe', 'pipe']
});

// process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
// process.stdin.pipe(spawned_process.stdin);

spawned_process.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
spawned_process.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);

spawned_process.on('exit', function (code) {
  process.exit(code);
});
```

This work well too and with `event-stream` module, I can parse and modify stream.

But I have this message:

> Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal

If I pipe `process.stdin` with commented code, I have same message for input and `ssh` command doesn't work without `-tt` flag.

I try this too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const child_process = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');
const tty = require('tty');
const command = ['vi', ['index.js']];

// find in `ttys` module code
let ttyFd = fs.openSync('/dev/tty', 'w');

let stdout = new tty.WriteStream(ttyFd);
stdout._type = 'tty';

if (stdout._handle && stdout._handle.unref) {
  stdout._handle.unref();
}

if (stdout._refreshSize) {
  process.on('SIGWINCH', function() {
    stdout._refreshSize();
  })
}

stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

var spawned_process= child_process.spawn(...command, {
    env: process.env,
    shell: '/bin/bash',
    stdio: [process.stdin, stdout, process.stderr]
});
```

Here too I can use `event-stream` module to do what I want but this code doesn't work, only one input on two works.

I would like to have the behavior of the first block code, no warning message with `vi`, `ssh` great but can edit the stream as second block code.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> I try wrap command in node script and parse stdin/out stream for add/replace string.

From what i understand the following is the way to handle a pipe

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {

  process.stdout.write(data);

});
```

I hope this helps